# Pop-up div to stay in center of visible screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

```
<style>
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 562px;
    height: 380px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

I am trying to popup the div "white_content" in the middle of the currently visible screen when a link is clicked. Even though the div will stay with the scroll, I want it to come up in the center visible screen. The black overlay just greys out the background.

Comment: I took the css-code from adeno and played around a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/MeFmm/2/

Answer (score 2):

To get the popup to center, position it 50% from the top and left, then subtract half the popups size with the margins

```
.white_content {
    display  : none;
    position : fixed;
    top      : 50%;
    left     : 50%;
    width    : 562px;
    height   : 380px;
    margin   : -190px 0 0 -281px;
    z-index  : 1002;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LMt3S/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To get the white box perfectly in the center you need to set `top` and `left` to 50%, then subtract half the width and height using `margin`, in this case `margin: -190px 0 0 -281px;`

Answer (score 0):

Adendeo's answer above works for your case because you know the dimensions of your popup. Another technique, if your browser support requirements allow, is to use `translate` rather than a hardcoded pixel value:

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This works because `translate` calculates its length values based on the size of the *element*, not its container.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.white_content {
    visibility: hidden; 
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Is this the class i have to apply to a div that should be centered?
I created this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/dRK68V5RcgWyvWJOj3Iy?p=preview and changed the size of the div to simulate longer content. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. top:50% and left:50% is the only new thing here and that will do the trick.

Comment: According to my understanding your solution does not achieve what op is asking for. Could you fork http://plnkr.co/edit/dRK68V5RcgWyvWJOj3Iy?p=preview to show your solution at work?